# SSRS: Use parameter selection as a condition in Query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

How to use parameter values as a condition in SSRS Query..
 [image]

### parameters:

```
date_from :datetime 
date_to :datetime
cust: text (label:Yes , Value :Y & Label :No , value:N)
```

Query:

```
SELECT dbo.incident.incident_ref,Customer.cust_n,incident.date_logged 
FROM incident
INNER JOIN Customer ON incident.incident_id = Customer.cust_id
WHERE incident.date_logged BETWEEN @date_from AND DATEADD(day, 1, @date_to)
```

I would to use a condition here to display customer based on my selection in `dropdownlist` (Include ABC)

Comment: Reference: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rt0ns.png

Comment: Could you clarify what 'ABC' actually references to? When 'Yes' is selected what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I have lot of values in "customer.cust_n" filed . If i selet yes , i need to include customer "ABC" in the report result , otherwise no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the query to:

```
SELECT dbo.incident.incident_ref,Customer.cust_n,incident.date_logged 
FROM incident
INNER JOIN Customer ON incident.incident_id = Customer.cust_id
WHERE 
    incident.date_logged BETWEEN @date_from AND DATEADD(day, 1, @date_to) and
    customer.cust_n = (case when @cust = 'N' and customer.cust_n = 'ABC' then NULL else customer.cust_n end)
```

Comment: Thanks , Its perfect . is there any way i can add one more filter in query after adding Last "N" Days . I need to select any one of filter either dates or last n days ..